# Passing an array of different-sized objects to a CUDA kernel

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I have an array of pointers to an abstract class `A`. These pointers point to objects of class `B`,`C` and they all derive from `A`. The sizes of these derived classes are not the same, so they have a function called `size` that returns a `size_t` of their size.

MCVE:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    float a;
    A() {}
    __host__ __device__ virtual size_t size() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    float b;
    B() {}
    __host__ __device__ virtual size_t size() override { return sizeof(*this); }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    float c, d;
    C() {}
    __host__ __device__ virtual size_t size() override { return sizeof(*this); }
};

__global__ void testKernel(A** objects, int numObjects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", objects[i]->size());
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> host_pointers;
    host_pointers.push_back(new B());
    host_pointers.push_back(new C());

    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    std::vector<A*> device_pointers;
    for (auto obj : host_pointers) {
        A* device_pointer;

        cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&device_pointer, obj->size());
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed for size %d\n", obj->size());
            exit(-1);
        }

        cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(device_pointer, obj, obj->size(), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
            fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed for size %d\n", obj->size());
            exit(-1);
        }
        device_pointers.push_back(device_pointer);
    }
    ///By this point, both objects should have been copied over
    ///to device memory, and I should have valid pointers to them
    A** array_of_device_pointers;

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&array_of_device_pointers, device_pointers.size() * sizeof(A*));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(array_of_device_pointers, device_pointers.data(), device_pointers.size() * sizeof(A*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    testKernel<<<1, 1>>>(array_of_device_pointers, device_pointers.size());

    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "kernel failed, reason: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
    }
    
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSynchronize failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

What I want to do: have objects derived from `A` in a kernel

How I'm trying to do it: copy the objects to device memory one by one (since their sizes aren't the same), then copy an array of their device pointers to device memory, and then pass a device pointer to that onto a kernel

What I experience: When I run the program with the Nsight debugger, it stops at the line
`printf("%d\n", objects[i]->size());`, (I'm guessing) meaning that object[0] is not a valid pointer.

Not sure if it matters with something this simple, but I'm running this on a GPU with compute capability 8.6, though compiling for compute capability 5.2

Comment: A side note: `sizeof(this)` will give you the size of `this` which is a pointer, not the size of your class object. You probably meant `sizeof(*this)` .

Comment: "If an object is created in host code, invoking a virtual function for that object in device code has undefined behavior." [CUDA C++ Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#virtual-functions). The pointers in the vtables copied to the device with the objects are probably pointing to the host versions of the virtual functions.